# Tortoisehg: failed to refresh [Errno 13: Permission denied]

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am using Tortoisehg and my repo is located on a network drive.  All files except one folder have been previously committed to the repo.

I right clicked on the network drive directory and selected Hg Commit

Immediately after the Hg Commit application starts, a dialog pops up showing "failed to refresh [Errno 13: Permission denied]"

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Don't place repo on network drive, obviously - this is always **The Bad Idea (tm)**

Comment: Why was it able to commit the first time?  I actually had a another hg repo on the network drive for a long time without any problems, but I had cloned that repo on my local drive.  I only needed to push the changes to the network once in a while.  I'll probably try that with this repo.

Comment: Ok.  cloning the repo to my local drive and pushing the changes to the network drive is the best way to go.